# Scaling down image

Tags: html, css

Guys how to make this kind of things in creating a website

This is the full picture:
[image]

When I scale down the browser it will turn out like this
[image]

Comment: It's called responsive web design. Research it.

Comment: if you are using Bootstrap. You can use img-fluid class in the image tag.

Comment: Do some research on CSS Media Queries.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `@media` rules. With `@media` rules you can not only apply different designs for different output devices (screen, printer, braille, ...), you can also specify **different designs for different screen sizes**.

Example:

```
p {
    font-size: 120%;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    p {
        font-size: 110%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

Other possible properties are `max-height`, `min-width` and `min-height`.

The rules can be combined:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-height: 800px) {}
```

[Media Queries - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: Just to say: `@media` rules are indeed one very good idea for solving this issue but they are by no means the only solution.

Comment: Bootstrap uses `@media` rules behind the scenes, too. Javascript would be an idea, but might be disabled and would add a lot of (unnecessary) complexity to the page. @Martin, what other solutions do you mean?

Comment: Another way would be to use **percentages** for dimensions. But this works only in a few cases. The otherwise very useful units **`vw` and `vh`** have poor browser support.

Comment: I was Looking at the image performance specifically and what I had in mind was `background-size:cover;` etc. or (with some added complexity) setting an `img{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }` type of specific reference. (But there is nothing at all wrong with your answer).